# Convert code snipet from Java to Apex

Tags: apex, java, httprequest

I am trying to do an api call and am getting a 403 error. I am putting the apex code below that is getting the 403 error. We opened a ticket with the company that we are sending the callout to and they do not know apex and gave us java code. I am a bit confused because it looks like it is converting text to base64 but I am not totally sure. any help on getting syntax updated or getting a better question to the providers help desk would be greatly appreciated.

apex callout code below

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://viewsonic.freshservice.com/api/v2/tickets');
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
request.setHeader('Authorization','xxxxxxxxxxxxx');
// Set the body as a JSON object
request.setBody('{"email":"test.orbison@vikkewsonic.com","phone":"9095551212","status":"2",'
                +'"priority":"1","source":"Yammer","subject":"test something",'+
                '"description":"description"}');

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
system.debug('status code '+response.getStatusCode());
```

Here is the java that the provider gave us

```
String credential = Base64.encodeToString( (username+":"+password).getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
httpGet.setHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + credential.substring(0, credential.length()-1));
```

edited: removed key

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, Http basic auth uses base64. The `Base64.encodeToString` in the Java snippet should've also given that away.

Given what you've shown so far, your Authorization header is incorrect.

If you inspect an actual, working request, you would see the authorization header appear like `Authorization: Basic <base64 string here>`. The "Basic" part is important, and is part of the header's value.

In Apex, you'd set that like

```
// The space between the auth scheme ("Basic" in this example, "Bearer" is another
//   common one) and the value is important
request.setHeader('Authorization','Basic ' + myBase64String);
```

As for how to get `myBase64String`, the Java way and the Apex way aren't too different. In Apex, it'd be something like

```
String externalUsername = 'some username';
String externalPassword = 'c is for cookie';

// base64Encode() takes a blob as an input, so we need to do just a little
//   work.
// String -> Blob
// Blob -> base64 encoded string
Blob credentialsBlob = Blob.valueOf(externalUsername + ':' + externalPassword);
String myBase64String = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(credentialsBlob);
```

Comment: Thanks. I like good simple answers.